# Using Filetables with Breeze

Tags: breeze, single-page-application

We are building a Single Page Application using Durandal , Knockout , Breeze , EF5 and WebApi as part of the application we want to store/manage files in database (SQL Sever 2012) , we are looking at Filetables as one of the ways to achieve this , does Breeze support FileTables (as EF doesnot )

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the NoDb sample in the Breeze.zip. It works with an in-memory datastore on the server. You could probably modify this to work with SQL server filetables, but my guess is that this is probably a good deal of work.

Comment: If you are going to use EF to save your other (non-file) data, another option is to use the `BeforeSaveEntities` and `AfterSaveEntities` methods (as described in the [ContextProvider documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider) to strip out your file data from the change set and save it manually, while letting EF save the rest.